# SELECT USING UNION QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql

I  wrote  two sql select queries and join it using 'union'.
But the output was mixed.I want the first queries output first and so on.
How it be possible. My SQL fiddle given below.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/17ad8/2)

Comment: Using sqlfiddle is great idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with `union all`:

```sql
select SUBSTR(name, 1, 2) from customer
union all
select SUBSTR(name, 1, 3) from customer
;
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to see first queries first. You can use union all

```
select SUBSTR(name,1, 2) from customer
union ALL
select SUBSTR(name,1, 3) from customer;
```

If you want to order by name you can use

```
select SUBSTR(name,1, 2) from customer
union
select SUBSTR(name,1, 3) from customer
order by substr;
```